# Edit List of Numbers n to contain only from 0 to n

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The title isn't very good mainly because its become quite difficult for me to describe the problem in a very concise manner. If someone can improve the title after reading below then please do so.

The problem is this. The input is an array of numbers like this : `[1,3,4,7]` and output is to be an array something like this : `[1,2,3,4]`. This is to indicate what rank each number is in the input array based on its value.

Some other examples :

```
In[1] : [4,3,7,9]

Out[1] : [2,1,3,4]


In[2] : [0,4,1,9]

Out[2] : [0,2,1,3]

In[3] : [1,0,0,0]
Out[3] : [1,0,0,0]
```

A peculiarity to notice here is that when an array contains zero it must start ranking from zero whereas for `In[1]` since it doesn't contain zero, the array starts ranking from 1.

Currently, I am using this code :

```
def argsort(seq):
    ix = list(range(len(seq)))
    ix.sort(key=lambda x: seq[x])
    out = [0] * len(i)
    for i, x in enumerate(ix):
        if seq[x] != 0:
            out[x] = i

    if 0 in seq:
        return out
    else:
        return [each+1 for each in out]
```

Currently, the solution works for the first two cases. However, it fails on case 3 and returns this as the result : `[3,0,0,0]`

Comment: Okay, so you have told us what you are currently doing, what is the problem? please specify the difference between what you have and what you want

Comment: @JesseBarnett Absolutely correct. Forgive me. Will edit to reflect.

Comment: can you check solution provided by me ? it works for all 3 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've a python list not numpy array (as you've tagged), so you can simply do it like this:

```
inList = [4,3,7,9]
sortedinList = sorted(set(inList))
outList = [sortedinList.index(e)+ (0 not in inList) for e in inList]
```

Since you want the same index for the duplicates, so you can use `set` instead of a `list` to get the index.

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> inList = [4,3,7,9]
>>> outList
[2,1,3,4]


>>> inList = [0,4,1,9]
>>> outList
[0,2,1,3]

>>> inList = [1,0,0,0]
>>> outList
[1,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure where i tagged numpy array, I simply tagged as "arrays" correct? Please let me know so i can fix it if i have made a mistake.

Comment: python has lists, numpy has arrays in python.

Comment: Ah. Correct. Will edit to reflect. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: @MacAhmed is this the required output? look at the updated answer with the output

Comment: Just tested with ```[1,0,0,0]``` and the result is ```[3,0,0,0]```.

Comment: @MacAhmed I'm getting `[1,0,0,0]`, please mind the change here :  `sorted(set(inList))`, i.e, addition of `set`

Comment: With the new ```set```, it does seem to be working fine. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
def argsort(seq):
    sorted_seq = sorted(seq)
    res = []

    for _ in sorted_seq:
        my_index = seq.index(_)
        res.append(my_index)
        seq[my_index] = '$'
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = [4,3,7,9]

    print argsort(seq=my_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Here is another alternative solution, I hope this resolves your question.

Comment: Just checked for ```[1,0,0,0]``` and the result was ```[1,2,3,0]```

Comment: expected is [1,0,0,0] ?